# Biometrico Digital Person en una Aplicacion de Consola c#

Tags: c#

como puedo utilizar el Biométrico Digital Persona en una aplicación de Consola, este es el código para una aplicación de Tipo Windows Forms:

```
namespace Form
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form, DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
  {
    public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }
    public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample)
    { }
    public void OnFingerGone(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnFingerTouch(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnReaderConnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnReaderDisconnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnSampleQuality(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, CaptureFeedback CaptureFeedback)
    { }
  }
 }
```

Y este seria el codigo, para una aplicación de tipo Console Applicacion:

```
 namespace Console_App
 {
  class Program:DPFP.Capture.EventHandler
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
    public void OnComplete(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, Sample Sample)
    { }
    public void OnFingerGone(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnFingerTouch(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnReaderConnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnReaderDisconnect(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber)
    { }
    public void OnSampleQuality(object Capture, string ReaderSerialNumber, CaptureFeedback CaptureFeedback)
    { }
  }
  }
```

¿Como podria llamar a los eventos desde el MAIN de la Consola?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder a los métodos desde el `Main` de tu aplicación debido al nivel de protección de los métodos.

---

Los métodos deben ser métodos *estáticos*:

Por ejemplo cambia:

```
public void OnComplete () { ... }
```

a

```
static void OnComplete () { ... }
```

Consulta [el modificador de acceso *static*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) para mas información.

Comment: ¿Existe alguna razón en específico para que se declaren los métodos como `private static ...`?

Comment: @Flxtr la aplicación de consola del OP muestra que su método principal es un método estático. Debido a que _por ejmeplo_, el método `OnComplete` es un método público, no se puede acceder/usar este método público desde método `Main`. Tuve un problema similar hace meses.

Comment: Me parece que realmente no importa que sean `private`, lo que sí importa es que sean `static`, es decir, puedes declarar el método como `public static ...`

Comment: y como accedo desde el Main

Comment: @Rastalovely, usa: `static void Main(string[] args) {  OnComplete(Capture, ReaderSerialNumber, Sample);  }`.